# Magento 2.4.5 image in order email

Tags: magento2.4.5

In my magento 2.4.3 the code below was working fine to get an image in order emails. But in my test environment 2.4.5-p1 there is an error regarding the $_imageHelper

In my 2.4.3 this was in my theme Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate

/** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items */
?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
```

```
<?php $_items = $_order->getAllItems(); ?>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px">Artikel</th>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px">Art.nr</th>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px">Afbeelding</th>
            <th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px">Aantal</th>
            <th align="right" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px">Subtotaal</th>
        </tr>        
    </thead>    
    <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
    <?php
        if ($_item->getParentItem()) {
            continue;
        }
    ?>
    <tbody>
        <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
    </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>    
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" align="right">
                <table>
                    <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?> 
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>        
<?php if ($this->helper(\Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message::class)
        ->isMessagesAllowed('order', $_order, $_order->getStore())
    && $_order->getGiftMessageId()
) : ?>
    <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper(\Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message::class)
        ->getGiftMessage($_order->getGiftMessageId()); ?>
    <?php if ($_giftMessage) : ?>
        <br />
        <table class="message-gift">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Gift Message for this Order')) ?></h3>
                    <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('From:')) ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                    <br /><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('To:')) ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                    <br /><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Message:')) ?></strong>
                    <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And this in Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate

/** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems */

/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
$_item = $block->getItem();
$_order = $_item->getOrder();
?>

  <!--- deze body herhalen per product -->
<tbody bgcolor="#F6F6F6">
<tr>
     <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <strong style="font-size:11px;"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <img src="<?= $_imageHelper->init($_item->getProduct(), 'small_image', ['type'=>'small_image'])->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('225','150')->getUrl();?>" alt="<?= __('Product Image');?>">
     </td>
     
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() * 1 ?>
    </td>
    <td align="right" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <span class="price">
            <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
<?php if ($_item->getGiftMessageId()
&& $_giftMessage = $this->helper(\Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message::class)
    ->getGiftMessage($_item->getGiftMessageId())
) : ?>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="item-extra">
    <table class="message-gift">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Gift Message')) ?></h3>
                <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('From:')) ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                <br /><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('To:')) ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                <br /><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Message:')) ?></strong>
                <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

Getting error  main.CRITICAL: Exception: Warning: Undefined variable $_imageHelper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare `$_imageHelper` variable before use:

```
$_imageHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image::class);
```

The result, your Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml file should be like the following:

```
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate

/** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems */

/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
$_item = $block->getItem();
$_order = $_item->getOrder();
$_imageHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image::class);
?>

<!--- deze body herhalen per product -->
<tbody bgcolor="#F6F6F6">
    <tr>
         <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
            <strong style="font-size:11px;"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
            <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?>
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
            <img src="<?= $_imageHelper->init($_item->getProduct(), 'small_image', ['type'=>'small_image'])->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('225','150')->getUrl();?>" alt="<?= __('Product Image');?>">
         </td>

        <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $_item->getQtyOrdered() * 1 ?>
        </td>
        <td align="right" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
            <span class="price">
                <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<!--- Eind body herhalen per product -->

<?php if ($_item->getGiftMessageId()
&& $_giftMessage = $this->helper(\Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message::class)
    ->getGiftMessage($_item->getGiftMessageId())
) : ?>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="item-extra">
        <table class="message-gift">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Gift Message')) ?></h3>
                    <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('From:')) ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                    <br /><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('To:')) ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                    <br /><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Message:')) ?></strong>
                    <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```